# Airflow bridge 1.10.15 - Ensure users are not using custom metaclasses in custom operators

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm running the Airflow bridge 1.10.15 version so we can migrate to Airflow 2, and I ran airflow upgrade_checkand I'm seeing this FAILED:

> Ensure users are not using custom metaclasses in custom operators

This is what I've found in the documentation that I think pertains to this error:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a17db7883044889b2b2001cefc41a8960359a23f/UPDATING.md#baseoperator-uses-metaclass

> BaseOperator class uses a BaseOperatorMeta as a metaclass. This meta
> class is based on abc.ABCMeta. If your custom operator uses different
> metaclass then you will have to adjust it.

Can someone please explain this to me? I have several custom operators that look like the below:

> ```
> class _FacebookOperator(BaseOperator):
>     @apply_defaults
>     def __init__(self,
>                  *args, **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         self.local_folder = 'FBOOK'
>         self.fbhook = None
> ```

I feel the documentation is vague when it says:

> If your custom operator uses different metaclass then you will have to
> adjust it.

I'm not entirely sure where the error is coming from, it doesn't show where its failing.